# What's a generic name for an attack animal?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for the name of an animal trained to attack, whether for defense or sport. I feel like it's on the 'tip of my tongue' but can't quite get it.

“Blood sport” is a bit too broad (and, in a sense, too narrow as well), and refers of course to the act and not the creature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about *fighting*? *Fighting bull*, *fighting dog*, *fighting cock* (yes, *gamecock* might be more common, but I'm trying to make a point here). I don't see a reason why other animals trained to fight cannot be called the same, be them hamsters or narwhals.

Comment: Now I'm picturing hamsters trained to attack narwhals like a pack of lemmings.

Answer (score 3):

A dog trained to attack is called an attack dog.  A dog trained for sentry duty is called a guard dog.  A dog trained for fighting is called a fighting dog.  I can't think of a single word that encompasses all of these types of training.

Answer (score 2):

*Sentry* or *guard* animal are two possibilities in the defense category:

> Section 1-14 – Dogs or other Animals
>   Used for Sentry or Guard Duty
>
> Any person owning, maintaining, or
>   harboring a dog or other animal for
>   sentry or guard purposes must register
>   said dog or other animal with the
>   Animal Control Director.
>
> A sign warning that there is a guard or
>   sentry animal on the premises must be
>   displayed such that persons are made
>   aware of the presence of a guard or
>   sentry animal before they enter the
>   property. Such sign shall specify what
>   type of animal the guard or sentry
>   animal is.

from the [Franklin County, NC, Animal Control Ordinance](http://www.co.franklin.nc.us/ac/ANIMAL%20CONTROL%20ORDINANCE%20rev%203.pdf)